# i already set the working directory and install packages, the problem start when r couldnt find object "SSB"

Tags: object

Im trying to solve Nominal-Interval using ETA-Squared.I alrealdy intall the packages and set working directory but the problem start with couldnt find the object "SSB".From there R couldnt run anymore and kept on couldnt find object. Iwant to know wheter my command is wrong or the spelling is wrong.Thus, i couldnt find the answer